# Using Groovy Script in sopaUI - Copy the content of a XML Holder to Another (Trying to CLONE the SOAP request Test Step)

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I am a newbie to groovy scripting and seeking your help to find a solution to the issue I am facing at the moment.

My requirement is that, on each iteration based on the test data input, I will have to remove a particular node or certain nodes from the SoapRequest. In order to achieve that I created two identical SOAP Request -Original and Modified.

Using groovy script I am trying to restore the content of the modified soap request with the content of the original soap request after each iteration. (Iteration 1 -  Node to delete is  and in second iteration node to delete is  keeping  - This is the reason for restoring the request with the original content). In other words want to clone the soap request so that the delete node operations can be performed on the cloned request keeping the original request unchanged.

The below are my Teststeps under my TestSuite.

Datasource
Original (SoapRequest)
Groovy Script.
Modified (SoapRequest)

**SoapRequest (Original)**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:idm="http://vedaxml.com/vxml2/idmatrix-v2-0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <idm:request>
         <idm:dataset-searches>
            <idm:profile-name></idm:profile-name>
         </idm:dataset-searches>
         <idm:individual-name>
            <idm:family-name>ABC</idm:family-name>
            <idm:first-given-name>DEF</idm:first-given-name>
         </idm:individual-name>
         <idm:date-of-birth>1985-12-12</idm:date-of-birth>
      </idm:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**My Groovy Script is as below**

```
def grUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def ReqHolder2 = grUtils.getXmlHolder("Modified#Request")

ReqHolder2.removeDomNodes("//idm:request")
ReqHolder2.updateProperty()

ReqHolder2 ["//soapenv:Body"] = context.expand( '${Original#Request#//idm:request}' )
ReqHolder2.updateProperty()
```

When I execute the above groovy script, the Modified request is updated with the content from the Original request but with CDATA and reference to the schema.

**SoapRequest (Modified)**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:idm="http://vedaxml.com/vxml2/idmatrix-v2-0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>***<![CDATA[<idm:request xmlns:idm="http://vedaxml.com/vxml2/idmatrix-v2-0.xsd">***
         <idm:dataset-searches>
            <idm:profile-name/>
         </idm:dataset-searches>
         <idm:individual-name>
            <idm:family-name>ABC</idm:family-name>
            <idm:first-given-name>DEF</idm:first-given-name>
         </idm:individual-name>
         <idm:date-of-birth>1985-12-12</idm:date-of-birth>
      </idm:request>**]]>**</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with this. Also, I would be glad to know/learn other alternative ways in groovy to implement this requirement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading on Groovy [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper) and [XmlParser](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlParser). They are very simple to implement and you could use them for your xml manipulation. However, for your particular requirement, using XmlParser would make more sense.

Here is a different question and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620465/properly-iterating-through-xml-with-namespaces-in-groovy/11625202#11625202), just to help you get an idea of how XMLParser works

And since your question is more about deleting nodes and less about accessing/validating them. Here is an [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201111/really-deleting-nodes-in-xmlparser-object-groovy) on SO about deletion of nodes using XMlParser.

Comment: Thanks Vamsi. Much appreciate your response. Will read through it. Actually, I have two parts to my requirement. The question above is first part of the requirement. I will need to copy the  content of a soap request to another and then perform delete nodes operations on the second one. For subsequent iterations will have to copy the content from the first soap request (original - which will not change) to the second and perform delete operation and so on. Hope it make sense. In an other way I am trying to clone the request and perform delete node operation on the cloned request.