# How to avoid the content appearing within CDATA when doin a UpdateProperty() - Groovy Scripting

Tags: groovy, soapui, cdata

Apologies for posting a smiliar question to my earlier one [Using Groovy Script in sopaUI - Copy the content of a XML Holder to Another (Trying to CLONE the SOAP request Test Step)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625796/using-groovy-script-in-sopaui-copy-the-content-of-a-xml-holder-to-another-try/11625966#11625966)

In my earlier question, I just realised that I had missed out mentioning my concern about CDATA ...which I think could have mislead in others understadning what my actual concern was. my bad!!

reiterating wat I had done.

**SoapRequest (Original)**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:idm="http://vedaxml.com/vxml2/idmatrix-v2-0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <idm:request>
         <idm:dataset-searches>
            <idm:profile-name></idm:profile-name>
         </idm:dataset-searches>
         <idm:individual-name>
            <idm:family-name>ABC</idm:family-name>
            <idm:first-given-name>DEF</idm:first-given-name>
         </idm:individual-name>
         <idm:date-of-birth>1985-12-12</idm:date-of-birth>
      </idm:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**My Groovy Script is as below**

```
def grUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def ReqHolder2 = grUtils.getXmlHolder("Modified#Request")

ReqHolder2.removeDomNodes("//idm:request")
ReqHolder2.updateProperty()

ReqHolder2 ["//soapenv:Body"] = context.expand( '${Original#Request#//idm:request}' )
ReqHolder2.updateProperty()
```

When I execute the above groovy script, the Modified request is updated with the content from the Original request but the updated content is within the CDATA and reference to the schema.

**SoapRequest (Modified)**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:idm="http://vedaxml.com/vxml2/idmatrix-v2-0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>***<![CDATA[<idm:request xmlns:idm="http://vedaxml.com/vxml2/idmatrix-v2-0.xsd">***
         <idm:dataset-searches>
            <idm:profile-name/>
         </idm:dataset-searches>
         <idm:individual-name>
            <idm:family-name>ABC</idm:family-name>
            <idm:first-given-name>DEF</idm:first-given-name>
         </idm:individual-name>
         <idm:date-of-birth>1985-12-12</idm:date-of-birth>
      </idm:request>**]]>**</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Could you please suggest how could I avoid updating the XML within CDATA. Rather update the XML properly. Kindly advice.

Comment: Vamsi Emani I am counting on you to answer this for me mate :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Modified Request to:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:idm="http://vedaxml.com/vxml2/idmatrix-v2-0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>${test123}</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And change your groovy to:

```
def grUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def ReqHolder2 = grUtils.getXmlHolder(context.expand( '${Original#Request#//idm:request}' ))
context.setProperty("test123", ReqHolder2.getXml())

testRunner.runTestStepByName( "Modified")

log.info(grUtils.getXmlHolder(context.expand( '${Modified#Request}')).getPrettyXml())
```

If you copy and paste the log into a text editor you will see:

```
Wed Jul 25 13:11:20 MDT 2012:INFO:<soapenv:Envelope     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:idm="http://vedaxml.com/vxml2/idmatrix-v2-0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <idm:request>
         <idm:dataset-searches>
            <idm:profile-name/>
         </idm:dataset-searches>
         <idm:individual-name>
            <idm:family-name>ABC</idm:family-name>
            <idm:first-given-name>DEF</idm:first-given-name>
         </idm:individual-name>
         <idm:date-of-birth>1985-12-12</idm:date-of-birth>
      </idm:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Chris :-) Much appreciate your response. This works for me.